# Facebook Open Graph - how to pass parameters in URL?

Tags: php, facebook, url, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

If I will try to pass this URL into Open Graph

```
$url = 'http://abc.com/index.php';
$facebook->api('/me/url_app:action','POST', array('something'=>$url));
```

everything is working well.
But if I try to add some parameters, like

```
$url = 'http://abc.com/index.php?a=b&c=d';
$facebook->api('/me/url_app:action','POST', array('something'=>$url));
```

then I will get this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Object at URL 'http://abc.com/index.php?a=b&c=d' of type 'url_app:action' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'. thrown in _PATH_/base_facebook.php on line 1050
```

Why I cannot add some parameters to the URL address?

**EDIT** Also, here is the PHP function for encoding link:

```
function encodeURIComponent($str) {
    $revert = array('%21'=>'!', '%2A'=>'*', '%27'=>"'", '%28'=>'(', '%29'=>')', '%3D'=>'=', '%3F'=>'?');
    return strtr(rawurlencode($str), $revert);
}
```

Comment: You do not have to encode anything when just giving a URL as a parameter to the api method. Have you tried running your URL through the debug tool – what does it say? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: @Cbroe is right, the debug tool is your best friend. In this case it seems that the meta tag at that URL is broken for og:url. Also, why do you encode like that? Suggest using http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php if you have to (you don't have to in this case, the SDK should do it for you).

Answer (score 0):

You have to urlencode your url.

> $url = encodeURIComponent('http://abc.com/index.php?a=b&c=d');
>   $facebook->api('/me/url_app:action','POST', array('something'=>$url));

This may solve your problem...

Comment: I've tried to use this function, but I've got similar error message: `Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#3503) "http%3A%2F%2Fabc.com%2Findex.php%3Fa%3Db" is an invalid value for property "shoe" with type "Reference" thrown in...`

Comment: _“You have to urlencode your url”_ – no, you don’t; not in this context.